# Escaping + character when read to passed as ajax data (to prevent concatenation)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading the value of an input text field and passing it to be used as ajax data

The field value has a `+`

```
<input name="someval" type="text" value="Receive (+ open)" />
```

and looks like when parsed with data, it parses the + as a jquery concatenation.

```
data: 'someval=' + $("input[name=someval]").val(),
```

This is the first time I notice this behavior.

- First, how do I solve it.
- Second, I have no way of knowing when the output might have these special chars, so is there a known best practice way to escape input so that whenever it happens we're covered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent):

```
'someval=' + encodeURIComponent($("input[name=someval]").val())
```

Better yet, let jQuery handle it for you:

```
data: { someval:$("input[name=someval]").val() }
```

jQuery will automatically escape your values (and keys) into the correct format (using [`jQuery.param()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.param)) for the data type (eg `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`).

Comment: So I guess every time it's possible that the input could contain special chars, I have to use this. Is this how it's done.

Comment: Chris, see my update to your other post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683198/jquery-ajax-response-removes-the-character/1683641#1683641